# cakephp 2.x - show some duplicate records while sorting and join model using default paginator

Tags: cakephp, pagination, left-join

I am using default paginator function `$this->paginate` for display data with produced from a query using joins.

Its working well but between pagination I found some duplicate records in the listing. It's also displaying a correct total number of records, and my database table has no duplicate records.

Here is my code:

```
$options['condition'] =some condition;
$options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'hoarding_categories',
                'alias' => 'HoardingCategory',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'HoardingCategory.hoarding_id = Hoarding.id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'general_categories',
                'alias' => 'GeneralCategory',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'HoardingCategory.category_id = GeneralCategory.id'
                ),
                'fields' => array('GeneralCategory.name')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'hoarding_images',
                'alias' => 'HoardingImage',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'HoardingImage.hoarding_id = Hoarding.id',
                    'HoardingImage.status = 1',
                ),
                'fields' =>      array('HoardingImage.image_name','HoardingImage.status')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'contract_hoardings',
                'alias' => 'ContractHoarding',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'ContractHoarding.hoarding_id = Hoarding.id',
                    'ContractHoarding.status = 1'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'contracts',
                'alias' => 'Contract',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Contract.id = ContractHoarding.contract_id'
                ),
                'fields' => array('Contract.contractID')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'plan_hoardings',
                'alias' => 'PlanHoarding',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'PlanHoarding.hoarding_id = Hoarding.id',
                    'PlanHoarding.is_deleted = 0',
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'plans',
                'alias' => 'Plan',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
//                    'Plan.id = Hoarding.plan_id',
                    'Plan.id = PlanHoarding.plan_id',
                    'Plan.is_plan_deleted = 0',
                    'Plan.campaign_status != 3'
                ),
                'fields' => array('Plan.display_name')
            )
            , 
            array(
                'table' => 'hoarding_mountings',
                'alias' => 'HoardingMountings',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'HoardingMountings.hoarding_id = Hoarding.id',
                    'Plan.is_plan_deleted = 0'
                ),
                'fields' => array('HoardingMountings.id', 'HoardingMountings.hoarding_id')
            )
            , 
            array(
                'table' => 'location_employees',
                'alias' => 'LocationEmployee',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'LocationEmployee.location_id = Hoarding.city_id',

                ),
                'fields' => array('LocationEmployee.*')
            ), 
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'alias' => 'User1',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User1.id = LocationEmployee.employee_id',
                ),
                'fields' => array('User1.name')
            )
        );

$fields = array('Hoarding.*','Hoarding.minimum_cost as total_minimum_cost','Hoarding.kiosk_qty as assigned_qty', 'Contract.contractID as contract_id', 'Plan.display_name as plan_name', 'HoardingImage.image_name as hoarding_image', 'HoardingImage.status as hoarding_image_status', 'GeneralCategory.name as category_id', 'User1.name as branch_manager_id');

$options['fields'] = $fields;
        $options['limit'] = $page_limit;
        $options['page'] = $page;
        $options['group'] = array('Hoarding.id');

$this->paginate = $options;//            
$data = $this->paginate('Hoarding'); ///Hoarding is my model name
```

Don't know why, but some duplicate records are returned randomly sometimes.

Here is my resulting query from Query log

```
`SELECT `Hoarding`.*, `Hoarding`.`minimum_cost` AS `total_minimum_cost`, `Hoarding`.`kiosk_qty` AS `assigned_qty`, `Contract`.`contractID` AS `contract_id`, `Plan`.`display_name` AS `plan_name`, `HoardingImage`.`image_name` AS `hoarding_image`, `HoardingImage`.`status` AS `hoarding_image_status`, `GeneralCategory`.`name` AS `category_id`, `User1`.`name` AS `branch_manager_id`, `Hoarding`.`id` FROM `homs_live`.`hoardings` AS `Hoarding` LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`hoarding_categories` AS `HoardingCategory` ON (`HoardingCategory`.`hoarding_id` = `Hoarding`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`general_categories` AS `GeneralCategory` ON (`HoardingCategory`.`category_id` = `GeneralCategory`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`hoarding_images` AS `HoardingImage` ON (`HoardingImage`.`hoarding_id` = `Hoarding`.`id` AND `HoardingImage`.`status` = 1) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`contract_hoardings` AS `ContractHoarding` ON (`ContractHoarding`.`hoarding_id` = `Hoarding`.`id` AND `ContractHoarding`.`status` = 1) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`contracts` AS `Contract` ON (`Contract`.`id` = `ContractHoarding`.`contract_id`) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`plan_hoardings` AS `PlanHoarding` ON (`PlanHoarding`.`hoarding_id` = `Hoarding`.`id` AND `PlanHoarding`.`is_deleted` = 0) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`plans` AS `Plan` ON (`Plan`.`id` = `PlanHoarding`.`plan_id` AND `Plan`.`is_plan_deleted` = 0 AND `Plan`.`campaign_status` != 3) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`hoarding_mountings` AS `HoardingMountings` ON (`HoardingMountings`.`hoarding_id` = `Hoarding`.`id` AND `Plan`.`is_plan_deleted` = 0) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`location_employees` AS `LocationEmployee` ON (`LocationEmployee`.`location_id` = `Hoarding`.`city_id`) LEFT JOIN `homs_live`.`users` AS `User1` ON (`User1`.`id` = `LocationEmployee`.`employee_id`)  WHERE ((`Hoarding`.`status` = ('A'))  AND  (((`Hoarding`.`standard_cost`  >= 0) AND (`Hoarding`.`standard_cost`  <= 1000000)))  AND  (`Hoarding`.`is_contract_expired` = '1'))  GROUP BY `Hoarding`.`id` ORDER BY `Hoarding`.`area_name` asc  LIMIT 25, 5`
```

When I run the same query in MySQL and just change to LIMIT 30,5 instead of `LIMIT 25,5`, it also returns a duplicate record sometimes.

Comment: Can you have a look at the query log and post us the resulting query? I think it's a messed up inner query...

Comment: @DIDoS edit my question and post resulting query from query log..thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have duplicates?

I've drawn part of the data model involved in the query:

[image: Data Model]

You are grouping by `hoardings.id`, which should get rid of the duplicates for the first three tables.

However, if your `location_employees` table holds more than one `employee_id` per `location_id` (which I suppose it does), then your query will produce duplicates. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: thanks for reply..but DB table dont have duplicate records..but the problem occurred when i used join model...if i remove all joins and simply used Hoarding table for displaying data,there is no duplicate records...there is one more column hid in my hoarding DB table..even i try to group by hoarding.hid .i also try DISTINCT for hoarding.id ,but still get duplicate records..so i got confused..what should i do for solving the problem?? really appreciated ur effords..

Comment: i also try with `Hoarding` and `plan_hoarding` tables only and removed all other joins ..still some duplicate records occurs...

Comment: Have you tried setting `$this->Hoarding->recursive=-1` before `find()`?

Comment: i tried `$this->Hoarding->recursive=2` before join model...before i tried `$this->Hoarding->recursive=3`...i think that was my mistake..i think my problem solved..thank you so much for reply..

Comment: I'm glad it worked! If you believe it solved your problem, perhaps you could mark the answer as accepted.